# Summary List of all subsites with relevant LISTS data

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, project-templates

Is it possible to view data of all subsites / sub project site from the parent site.

Example:

Project Site : ABC

Sub-Project sites: 
1) xyz 
2) pqr
c) def

All the sub-project sites contains multiple lists.

Project owner would like to view selective content from all lists hosted in the sub-projects once logged on the parent site.

I`m not sure how it can be achieved.
Please share relevant article that explains with examples if possible.

Answer (score 1):

For this there are multiple ways, one of the best approach is using CQWP which will display data from all the subsites.

May this question is already answered at [Accessing data from lists in sub-sites at parent site level](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36122/accessing-data-from-lists-in-sub-sites-at-parent-site-level)

Before moving forward have a look to this once.